# How to build a simple RSS reader in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, rss, python-3.7, feedparser

I built a simple RSS reader on Python and it is not working.
In addition, I want to get the featured image source link of every post and I didn't find a way to do so.

> it shows me the Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "RSS_reader.py", line 7, in 
>       feed_title = feed['feed']['title']

If there are some other RSS feeds that work fine. So I don't understand why there are some RSS feeds that are working and others that aren't

So I would like to understand why the code doesn't work and also how to get the featured image source link of a post
I attached the code, is written on Python 3.7

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser

feed = feedparser.parse("https://finance.yahoo.com/rss/")

feed_title = feed['feed']['title']
feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed.entries:

    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    article_published_at = entry.published # Unicode string
    article_published_at_parsed = entry.published_parsed # Time object
    article_author = entry.author
    content = entry.summary
    article_tags = entry.tags


    print ("{}[{}]".format(article_title, article_link))
    print ("Published at {}".format(article_published_at))
    print ("Published by {}".format(article_author))
    print("Content {}".format(content))
    print("catagory{}".format(article_tags))
```

Answer (score 11):

A few things.

1) First `feed['feed']['title']` does not exist.
2) At least for this site `entry.author, entry.tags` do not exist
3) It seems feedparser is not compatible with python3.7 (it gives me `KeyError, "object doesn't have key 'category'`)

So as a starting point try to run the following code in python 3.6 and go from there.

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser

feed = feedparser.parse("https://finance.yahoo.com/rss/")

# feed_title = feed['feed']['title']  # NOT VALID
feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed.entries:

    article_title = entry.title
    article_link = entry.link
    article_published_at = entry.published # Unicode string
    article_published_at_parsed = entry.published_parsed # Time object
    # article_author = entry.author  DOES NOT EXIST
    content = entry.summary
    # article_tags = entry.tags  DOES NOT EXIST


    print ("{}[{}]".format(article_title, article_link))
    print ("Published at {}".format(article_published_at))
    # print ("Published by {}".format(article_author)) 
    print("Content {}".format(content))
    # print("catagory{}".format(article_tags))
```

Good luck.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that whether feedparser is supported for now? It says it requires Python >= 3.6 at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use xml parser libraries like beatifulsoup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and create custom parsers. A sample customer parser code can be found here (https://github.com/vintageplayer/RSS-Parser). A walk through the same can read here (https://towardsdatascience.com/rss-feed-parser-in-python-553b1857055c)

Though libraries can be useful, beautifulsoup is an extremely handy library to try out.

Answer (score 2):

I have used BeautifulSoup for a beginner RSS feed reader project (You need to install lxml for it to work since we are dealing with xml):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = requests.get('https://realpython.com/atom.xml')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'xml')
entries = soup.find_all('entry')

for i in entries:
  title = i.title.text
  link = i.link['href']
  summary = i.summary.text
  print(f'Title: {title}\n\nSummary: {summary}\n\nLink: {link}\n\n------------------------\n')
```

You can find the Youtube video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HbqO-TfjlI