# Is there a way to programmtically check via an API on that status of Google Workspace Apps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-admin-sdk

Google has a [Google Workspace Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/) where they indicate whether any of their core services are experiencing an outage or not.

Accordingly, I would like to be able to fetch the status for a particular service. For example, I would like to check whether `Gmail` has one of the following statuses:

- Available
- Service disruption
- Service outage

I would like to make an API call in `Python` that would retrieve the status and allow me to perform an action according to the current status.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

I found some documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/AppsOutage) but I'm still trying to figure out how I can do it.

Comment: Use `https://www.google.com/appsstatus/dashboard/incidents.json` instead, you can find all the incidents as JSON, per dict object there is the service that experienced downtime with key `service_name` and other data. If you want GMail, i think you iterate through the key per object and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the API is that it does not work directly with the Dashboard, instead it works with the information from the `Google Workspace Alert Center`, meaning that you need to [set up an alert](https://support.google.com/a/answer/139569) first in order to pull the data from this specific alert using the API and the alert will only be triggered when there is a service disruption or outage reported in the Dashboard, so it will not show any data about the service being Available but only when there is an outage.

As mentioned by [Bijay Regmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8591711/bijay-regmi) and the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/139569#:%7E:text=Subscribe%20to%20the%20Status%20Dashboard%20RSS%20or%20JSON%20feeds), I think the best option would be to subscribe to the Status Dashboard RSS or use the JSON feeds.

With Python you could also create a RSS reader to pull that information in a better way, and you can use [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936200/how-to-build-a-simple-rss-reader-in-python-3-7) as a reference on how to build it.